# Google Sheets Add-On, custom menu not being added?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm currently trying to make a Google Sheets add-on for use by my office. I've gone through the work of getting it published privately in the marketplace and distributing it domain-wide, but I'm running into the issue of the menu items not being added properly. I've been reading about AuthMode, and from what I understand, my users will all be initially AuthMode.NONE, which should be able to add simple menus. Maybe my understanding of "simple menus" is different. I really need to get this working within a week before we switch all of our computers to ChromeOS (not my decision, IT's decision)

Here's what I assume should be all of the relevant code. Each function is properly defined as well.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu('Usage Macros')
        .addItem('Summarize', 'firstRun')
        .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu('Rate')
            .addItem('PG&E', 'pge')
            .addItem('CARE', 'care'))
        .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu('Proposal Type')
            .addItem('SunRun 0%', 'sunRun0')
            .addItem('SunRun 1.9%', 'sunRun19')
            .addItem('SunRun 2.5%', 'sunRun25')
            .addItem('SunRun 2.9%', 'sunRun29')
            .addItem('SunRun 3.5%', 'sunRun35')
            .addItem('SunPower 0%', 'sunPower0')
            .addItem('SunPower 2%', 'sunPower2')
            .addItem('SunNova 0%', 'sunNova0')
            .addItem('SunNova 0.9%', 'sunNova09')
            .addItem('SunNova 1.9%', 'sunNova19')
            .addItem('SunNova 2.9%', 'sunNova29')
            .addItem('Cash', 'cash')
            .addItem('GreenSky', 'greenSky')
            .addItem('EnerBank', 'enerBank'))
        .addItem('Finalize','kleanUp')
        .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}
```

I should also mention that the "Summarize" menu item and "firstRun" were added because originally the onOpen function called 2 other functions that changed some formatting and snipped useless info from the documents being opened. I removed that from the onOpen, and added a menu item for them, hoping it would help. Alas it did not.

Comment: So, the menu is being added?  Just not structured the way you want?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed how I wrote part of that does make it seem like that's what I said. But no, none of my menus are being added. The name of the add-on appears in the add-on menu, but the only thing in there is "Help"

Comment: Try putting the `onInstall()` function at the very top of `code.gs`.  I know that I've experienced some strange quirk in the past, but can't remember what it was.

Comment: I just tried that, and it's still not working when I test it as an add-on.

Comment: "If the script is published as an add-on, the caption parameter is ignored and the menu is added as a sub-menu of the Add-ons menu, equivalent to createAddonMenu()" [source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#createmenucaption)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus):

> If an add-on tries to create a top-level menu using the createMenu(name) syntax shown above, the *name argument is ignored* and the script is given an entry in the Add-ons menu under the add-on's published name.

Here what I have done to your code:

## Using the [createAddonMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createaddonmenu)

```
function onOpen(e) {
var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()

menu.addItem('Summarize', 'firstRun')
.addSubMenu(menu
.addItem('PG&E', 'pge')
.addItem('CARE', 'care'))
.addSubMenu(menu
.addItem('SunRun 0%', 'sunRun0')
.addItem('SunRun 1.9%', 'sunRun19')
.addItem('SunRun 2.5%', 'sunRun25')
.addItem('SunRun 2.9%', 'sunRun29')
.addItem('SunRun 3.5%', 'sunRun35')
.addItem('SunPower 0%', 'sunPower0')
.addItem('SunPower 2%', 'sunPower2')
.addItem('SunNova 0%', 'sunNova0')
.addItem('SunNova 0.9%', 'sunNova09')
.addItem('SunNova 1.9%', 'sunNova19')
.addItem('SunNova 2.9%', 'sunNova29')
.addItem('Cash', 'cash')
.addItem('GreenSky', 'greenSky')
.addItem('EnerBank', 'enerBank'))
.addItem('Finalize','kleanUp')
.addToUi();
}
```

## Result

### [image]

## Using the [createMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createmenucaption)

```
function onOpen(e) {
var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

menu.createMenu('Usage Macros')
.addItem('Summarize', 'firstRun')
.addSubMenu(menu.createMenu('Rate')
.addItem('PG&E', 'pge')
.addItem('CARE', 'care'))
.addSubMenu(menu.createMenu('Proposal Type')
.addItem('SunRun 0%', 'sunRun0')
.addItem('SunRun 1.9%', 'sunRun19')
.addItem('SunRun 2.5%', 'sunRun25')
.addItem('SunRun 2.9%', 'sunRun29')
.addItem('SunRun 3.5%', 'sunRun35')
.addItem('SunPower 0%', 'sunPower0')
.addItem('SunPower 2%', 'sunPower2')
.addItem('SunNova 0%', 'sunNova0')
.addItem('SunNova 0.9%', 'sunNova09')
.addItem('SunNova 1.9%', 'sunNova19')
.addItem('SunNova 2.9%', 'sunNova29')
.addItem('Cash', 'cash')
.addItem('GreenSky', 'greenSky')
.addItem('EnerBank', 'enerBank'))
.addItem('Finalize','kleanUp')
.addToUi();
}
```

## Result

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried copy and pasting the code into mine, and it still isn't adding the menus at all.

Comment: In the meantime the "Add-ons" menu was renamed to "Extensions".

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add an [onInstall()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#oninstalle) function that calls your onOpen() function.

> The most common use of onInstall(e) is simply to call onOpen(e) to add
>   custom menus. After all, when an add-on is installed, the file is
>   already open, and thus onOpen(e) doesn't run on its own unless the
>   file is reopened.

So:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Comment: And I'm just seeing this question is 2 years old... brought to the top of the activity page by an edit! Oh well -- this should still be the correct answer!

Comment: If you already have `onInstall` calling `onOpen` as described here, and the menus are created with `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My add-on').addItem(...)`, look in the logs for any errors that might have occurred before attempting to create the menu (e.g. permission issues, running into one of the many Apps Script [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814143/how-to-get-around-time-trigger-limitations-for-add-ons-in-google-app-script/57820818#comment123490084_57820818) etc.)